# Installing php5.5 in Wamp

Tags: php, localhost, wampserver, php-5.5

I am in the unfortunate position of needing to install php 5.5 on my wamp 3.1.3 installation to support some old code that will *hopefully* soon die.

I installed the files to here:

[image]

But when I go into the wamp menu to change the version, it's not showing up. Am I missing a setting somewhere?

I've exited and re-opened wamp, but that didn't help.

[image]

Comment: How did you install PHP5.5.9 as it is not one of the standard PHP-ADDON's available on WAMPServer download page. I assume you must have tried to do it maually

Comment: Using Docker is quite a good solution for these cases.

Comment: Install 5.5 manually from http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en&allversions=afficher. Hope it will help

Comment: @Anton PHP 5.5.9 is not available there, hence my first comment ;)

Comment: i just downloaded it from https://museum.php.net/php5/ and extracted and copied the files to the php folder in my wamp installation.

Comment: Would PHP5.5.38 be good enough for you. That is the oldest PHP5.5 version available on the download site for 64bit

Comment: at this point i'd try it...what was supposed to be a couple hours of work has turned into several days of headaches..

Comment: What you probably forgot to do was create a `wampserver.conf` file in the `wamp64/bin/php/php5.5.9` folder

Comment: i copied over the one from my 5.6 version. It didn't seem to make a difference with these settings:  
$phpConf['apache']['2.4']['LoadModuleName'] = 'php5_module';
$phpConf['apache']['2.4']['LoadModuleFile'] = 'php5apache2_4.dll';
$phpConf['apache']['2.4']['AddModule'] =  '';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the install of PHP5.5.9 that you have created in the wamp folder, what you probably forgot to do was create a `wampserver.conf` file in `wamp64\bin\php\php5.5.9\` folder.

It should look like this

```
<?php

$phpConf['phpIniDir'] = '.';
$phpConf['phpExeDir'] = '.';
$phpConf['phpConfFile'] = 'php.ini';

$phpConf['apache']['2.2']['LoadModuleName'] = 'php5_module';
$phpConf['apache']['2.2']['LoadModuleFile'] = 'php5apache2_2.dll';
$phpConf['apache']['2.2']['AddModule'] =  '';

$phpConf['apache']['2.4']['LoadModuleName'] = 'php5_module';
$phpConf['apache']['2.4']['LoadModuleFile'] = 'php5apache2_4.dll';
$phpConf['apache']['2.4']['AddModule'] =  '';

?>
```

> I think this version of PHP will run with Apache 2.4, but that just might be your next issue. In which case you may have to download an Apache 2.2 from the `http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en&allversions=afficher` site
>
> Also I hope you downloaded the 64bit version of that PHP as you appear to be using the 64bit WAMPServer and therefore 64bit Apache, so they have to match

You also seem to have downloaded the Source code and not the executables for PHP5.5.9. Download the executables code from [The PHP Archive](https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/php-5.5.9-Win32-VC11-x64.zip)

Here is my old [HOW TO MANUALLY INSTALL A NEW RELEASE OF PHP INTO THE WAMPSERVER ENVIRONMENT Tutorial](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,135246,135248#msg-135248) see if that helps you get this going.

> Ping me if you have any questions on that.

Comment: how would i determine whether i downloaded the 32-bit or 64-bit. The listing on the site I downloaded from doesn't show that..

Comment: What did you download from the museum?

Comment: i used the link for php-5.5.9.tar.gz - https://museum.php.net/php5/php-5.5.9.tar.gz

Comment: As far as I can tell that is just Source Code. Did you compile it yourself?

Comment: i just extracted and copied it. I guess it wasn't that simple :(

Comment: Get the executables from here https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/php-5.5.9-Win32-VC11-x64.zip

Comment: ok, downloaded that, extracted it, copied the files over to my directory. I verified the wampserver.conf is the same as what you have listed and it's still not showing up in the versions after restarting wamp. Would there be any indication that I need apache 2.2? It's technically not even trying to use php5.5.9, it's still set to 5.6.

Comment: Good to hear that old tutorial is still of some use :)